# Can not remove Azure MoveCollection

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-powershell

Cannot remove a MoveCollectin in Azure. Tried it in portal or PS

```
Remove-AzResourceMoverMoveCollection -MoveCollectionName MoveCollection-eus-eus2-eus2 -ResourceGroupName ResourceMoverRG-eastus-eastus2-eus2
```

Here is the error:

```
Remove-AzResourceMoverMoveCollection_Delete: Deletion of move collection is not allowed when there are move resources present in it.
      Possible Causes: The move collection has move resources present in it.
      Recommended Action: In Portal open 'Azure Resource Mover' > Across regions > Select SubscriptionId: 14320207-c601-4e2c-99c4-57ffa57d4fef, Source Region: eastus, Target Region: eastus2 > delete all the resources, and then retry deleting the Resource group.
      For PowerShell please use remove resource cmdlet and delete all resources and then try deleting move collection or resource group. Please follow documentation  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2145903.
```

Tried to go to 'Azure Resource Mover' > Across regions, there is nothing there.

Please help!

Thanks in advance!

Tao

Answer (score 0):

From the **Azure Portal**, more particularly from the ResourceMoverRG **Overview** page, tick the "**Show hidden types**" option checkbox.

Once the "hidden" MoveCollection resource selected, delete it and then you'll be able to finally delete the ResourceMoverRG:

[image: ResourceMoverRG Overview page]

Comment: You may have to also delete any failed Deployments.